# Would Joe Biden lift the sanctions imposed on Huawei if he wins?

Tags: united-states, trade, sanctions, joe-biden

Has Joe Biden specifically said  anything about lifting sanctions imposed on Huawei if he wins the election?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct answer to your question is: **no, he has not made a specific statement as to what he plans to do about Huawei.**

His statements indicate that he is not really taking a position on the matter but wants to have options to either stay the course -or- walk back existing restrictions if he is elected.  He has not indicated what metrics or considerations he may use to make his decision(s).

In August of 2020, Biden indicated in an exchange with Lulu Garcia-Navarro of NPR that he would end Trump's tariffs on China but did not mention Huawei specifically.  Biden's aides later walked those statements back.

He has made other comments, best described non-committal, that he prefers an international approach and that he *supports* a ban on using Huawei equipment in the US (cited in divibisan's answer).  Despite this expression of support, he has not actually made a statement as to what he plans to do.

Answer (score 7):

Joe Biden has said that he will maintain the ban on Huawei equipment in the US:

> **Biden has similarly promised a more global approach to countering the influence of Chinese technology companies such as Huawei Technologies Co**. and TikTok-owner ByteDance Ltd. He acknowledged “genuine concern” about how TikTok handles data from its some 100 million American users, while faulting Trump for trying to make money off a deal to secure U.S. control over the social media network’s local business.

> **Biden said in February that he supported a ban on using Huawei equipment in the U.S**., although he’s said little about whether he would continue the Trump administration’s “Clean Network” program to convince allies to swear off Huawei products in critical communications networks. He has [said he would work](https://joebiden.com/americanleadership/) with “fellow democracies” to develop global rules on cybertheft, data privacy and artificial intelligence.
>
> [What Biden Has Said on Major U.S. Flashpoints With China](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-10-28/this-is-what-biden-s-said-on-major-u-s-flashpoints-with-china) - Bloomberg, October 28, 2020